# Simple form to add custom links to menu?

Tags: menus, widgets, sidebar, links

I currently have a menu set up called "sidebar links" with 5 custom URLs.

In my widgets section I have a Custom Menu which shows my "sidebar links" menu.

This basically gives my sidebar 5 links.

---

What I am looking to do is to make a simple html/php form which....

- You enter an URL and title then hit enter
- The form then adds this URL to the menu as a custom URL
- The form then removes the oldest link

Is this possible? I don't want to give people access to the menus part of the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you're talking about a widget of Links.... why not just use the default Links widget that was part of core up till 3.5?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/link-manager/

If you insist on limiting it to showing the latest 5 links, you're going to have to write a bit of code (that I'm not convinced is worth it).  Possible approaches include:

- Filtering the output of said Link Manager widget
- Creating a custom post type called 'Sidebar Links' and then writing your own widget that displays the 5 latest
- Creating a totally custom interface and storage mechanism from scratch (definitely not recommended)

Another options is using something like Options Framework (http://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/) to add some Theme Options.  You could add Link 1, Link 2, Link 3, Link 4, and Link 5 as options.  It's not an amazing user interface, but it's another quick way to accomplish basically what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried the link-manager, but it still has to be done via the dashboard and worst of all, there's nearly no options. I want to post news there from other sites and show the newest 5. link-manager means I have to manually set the order and it'll take far too long for anyone to add link, reorganise the posts, then save.

Comment: > "but it still has to be done via the dashboard"

Your question specifically says you didn't want to let them to them to the Menus part of the dashboard - are you trying to keep them out of the entire dashboard?

Comment: No... well put it this way.. this way is very convuluted and is a lot more complicated than it should be. It's so useless, I didn't bother using it. I want a simple form I can give to people where they can submit news URLs. I am not giving them dashboard access, and I am not patient enough to spend 10 minutes messing with the menu's just to get 1 link up there. I wanted a simple form where you type a header + url and press submit. Instead, people seem to rely on plugins which are far too complicated and not simple.